# roscd pointing to wrong location

Tags: rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Edit: Ah hah, this turned out to be a package problem, not a rospack problem. Sorry!

I have a package in an overlay. This same package exists in the /opt stacks.  My ROS_PACKAGE_PATH has the overlay before the /opt stacks.

```
/home/vchwang/ros_workspace/sandbox:/opt/ros/electric/stacks:/opt/ros/electric/ros
```

However, roscd still points to the one in /opt. As a result, rosmake refuses to build the package in my overlay. How do I change this?

Some more info:

Even after running rospack profile, my rospack_cache claims the package sbpl is in /opt/ros/electric/stacks/arm_navigation/sbpl. If I go into ~/ros_workspace/sandbox/sbpl and rosmake, I get:

[ rosmake ] No package selected and the current directory is not the correct path for package 'sbpl'.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52629/roscd-pointing-to-wrong-location/) by [vhwanger](https://answers.ros.org/users/3648/vhwanger/) on ROS Answers with karma: 52 on 2013-01-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-01-17**:
Please try to provide enough information for us to reproduce your error.  http://www.ros.org/wiki/Support You're saying it's doing the wrong thing, and people are guessing in the dark.

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2013-01-18**:
if you solved the problem, answer yourself and close the question.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2013-01-19**:
Can you post the whole rosmake message include the shell prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turns out I was getting the wrong version of the package, which did not contain a manifest file.

---

Originally posted by [vhwanger](https://answers.ros.org/users/3648/vhwanger/) with karma: 52 on 2013-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can try:

```
  rospack profile
```

Everytime I met such like roscd problems, I can solve it by this command.

But I'm not understand why rosmake refuce to make. What's that message?

Hope this helps you~

---

Originally posted by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) with karma: 2570 on 2013-01-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2